# Accessing A Particular Array By Value

Tags: php, arrays

Given the following array structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [widget_title] => Example
            [widget_content] => A bunch of content, including <strong>HTML</strong>.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [widget_title] => Example #2
            [widget_content] => Less content this time.
        )

)
```

What is the best way to access `widget_content` based on the value of `widget_title`?

For instance, I want to search for "Example" and return that first array, then store it to access the `widget_content` value.

Comment: could you please provide the php code?

Comment: I'd be happy too - Which code? I am trying to figure out how to accomplish what I described in PHP.

Comment: One idea I had was to identify the adjacent key/value pair to the given value.. It didn't seem like a clean approach, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of many ways to do it:

```
$filtered = array_filter($array, function($e){
    return $e['widget_title'] == 'Example';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
<?
$arrays = array(
            array(
                'widget_title' => 'Example',
                'widget_content' => 'A bunch of content, including <strong>HTML</strong>.'
            ),
            array(
                'widget_title' => 'Example #2',
                'widget_content' => 'Less content this time.'
            )
        );

$widget_title = 'Example';

foreach ($arrays as $array) {
    switch($array['widget_title']) {
        case $widget_title: echo $array['widget_content']; break;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I think that would have also done the job! Thank you for another suggestion!